# How to list all month between 2 dates with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've two dates

```
2015-3-30      2013-8-31
```

How can I make a month list like:

```
[ '2015-3', '2015-2', '2015-1', '2014-12', '2014-11', '2014-10', '2014-09', '2014-08', '2014-07', '2014-06', '2014-05'....., '2013-08' ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var startDate = moment('2021-12-31');
var endDate = moment('2022-12-14');
var betweenMonths = [];

if (startDate < endDate){
   var date = startDate.startOf('month');

   while (date < endDate.endOf('month')) {
      betweenMonths.push(date.format('YYYY-MM'));
      date.add(1,'month');
   }
}
```

Comment: if you choose a date range something like - 2016-08-16 to 2017-02-15, this logic alone won't be helpful. As the 'Feb-2017' won't be added. Simply because in the last iteration's start date will be 2017-02-16, which is greater than 2017-02-15

Comment: The correction by Alexander Swann (below) is the best answer and corrects this problem of the missing end month.

Comment: it working perfectly but my datestart value changes after. how do i resolve it

Comment: @AtchutharamareddyKarri I've updated my answer below to cater for this. You are right, it mutates the start date, so the below should now not alter it at all.

Answer (score 35):

I think the original answer isn't entirely correct, as you wouldn't get `'2015-3'` in your array. This is due to the fact your start date would eventually end up as `'2015-3-31'` and would fail the conditional in place. You could extend it like below.

UPDATE: I've now included cloning the dateStart variable so it isn't mutated at all.

```
var dateStart = moment('2013-8-31');
var dateEnd = moment('2015-3-30');
var interim = dateStart.clone();
var timeValues = [];

while (dateEnd > interim || interim.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
   timeValues.push(interim.format('YYYY-MM'));
   interim.add(1,'month');
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution to the "what about the last month?" problem with the primary accepted answer.  Thanks for adding it!  This one should receive the most upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

You are using multiple formats in the output: YYYY-MM and YYYY-M, so I picked the first. You can edit as you see fit.

```js
var startDateString = "2012-5-30";
var endDateString = "2015-8-31";
var startDate = moment(startDateString, "YYYY-M-DD");
var endDate = moment(endDateString, "YYYY-M-DD").endOf("month");

var allMonthsInPeriod = [];

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
  allMonthsInPeriod.push(startDate.format("YYYY-MM"));
  startDate = startDate.add(1, "month");
};

console.log(allMonthsInPeriod);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = allMonthsInPeriod.join("<br />");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try with this example

```
var one = moment("2015-3-30");
  var two = moment("2014-8-31");
  var dateDiffs = [];
  var count = Math.round(moment.duration(one.diff(two)).asMonths());

  month =  two.month() + 1;
  year  =  two.year();

  for (var i=1; i<=count; i++) {
      if (month > 12) {
        month = 1;
        year++;
      }
      dateDiffs.push(year+"-"+month);
      console.log(month);
      month++;
  }

  console.log(dateDiffs);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but your code has some problems if datediffs is more then 2 years, you can check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jcoyace0/

Comment: thanks for help, it works fine in chrome, but I got invalid date in firefox, I'm looking for a solution for this bug

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getMonths = (start, end) =>
    Array.from({ length: end.diff(start, 'month') + 1 }).map((_, index) =>
      moment(start).add(index, 'month').format('MM.YYYY'),
    );
    
const months = getMonths(moment('01.2019','MM.YYYY'),moment('01.2020','MM.YYYY'))
    
console.log(months)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way in my opinion.

```
const startDate = moment('2013-8-31', 'YYYY-M-DD');
const endDate = moment('2015-3-30', 'YYYY-M-DD');

const months = [];
const flag = startDate;
while (flag.diff(endDate) <= 0) {
  months.push(flag.format('YYYY-M'));
  flag.add(1, 'M');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just https://date-fns.org/v2.13.0/docs/eachMonthOfInterval ??

```js
// Each month between 6 February 2014 and 10 August 2014:
var result = eachMonthOfInterval({
  start: new Date(2014, 1, 6),
  end: new Date(2014, 7, 10)
})
//=> [
//   Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Sat Mar 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Thu May 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Sun Jun 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Tue Jul 01 2014 00:00:00,
//   Fri Aug 01 2014 00:00:00
// ]
```