# JavaScript: get all months between two dates?

Tags: javascript

I have two date strings like this:

```
var startDate = '2012-04-01';
var endDate = '2014-11-01';
```

And I want to end up with an array of strings like this:

```
var dates = ['2012-04-01', '2012-05-01', '2012-06-01' .... '2014-11-01',];
```

So far this is what I've got, but it's pretty ugly:

```
var startDate = '2012-04-01';
var endDate = '2014-11-01';
var start = new Date(Date.parse(startDate));
var end = new Date(Date.parse(endDate))
var dates = [];
for (var i = start.getFullYear(); i < end.getFullYear() + 1; i++) {
    dates.push(i + '-' + '-01');
}
console.log(dates);
```

Is there a better way? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvtcjq9x/).

Comment: Are the start and end dates always guaranteed to be midnight of the 1st of the month?

Comment: Your solution is readable and easy to prove correct (or easily fixable). I suspect that a 'better' solution based on Date objects or Julian values that advances month by month would actually end up being a worse solution. It would be less readable, probably bugged (for certain date inputs e.g. what is October 31st plus one month?), and much harder to prove its correctness.

Comment: It's more easy by using moment.js, please check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466944/how-to-list-all-month-between-2-dates-with-moment-js

Comment: Related to the various momentjs-inspired answers: [Moment is now a legacy project in maintenance mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### update (2024)

Revisiting this answer a decade later: this use case is easily solved by [`date-fns#eachMonthOfInterval`](https://date-fns.org/v3.2.0/docs/eachMonthOfInterval). For those interested in rolling their own, I would revise my original code to not rely on string parsing and instead lean on native Date operations:

```js
/**
 * dateRange returns an array of year-month dates between the supplied start and end dates
 * @param startDate Date or natively parseable string (e.g. 2024-04-01)
 * @param endDate Date or natively parseable string (e.g. 2024-04-01)
 * @returns string[] of ISO 8601 strings for each month between start and end
 */
function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {
  // we use UTC methods so that timezone isn't considered
  let start = new Date(startDate);
  const end = new Date(endDate).setUTCHours(12);
  const dates = [];
  while (start <= end) {
    // compensate for zero-based months in display
    const displayMonth = start.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    dates.push([
      start.getUTCFullYear(),
      // months are zero based, ensure leading zero
      (displayMonth).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      // always display the first of the month
      '01',
    ].join('-'));

    // progress the start date by one month
    start = new Date(start.setUTCMonth(displayMonth));
  }

  return dates;
}
```

### original answer (2014)

This should produce the desired output:

```
function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {
  var start      = startDate.split('-');
  var end        = endDate.split('-');
  var startYear  = parseInt(start[0]);
  var endYear    = parseInt(end[0]);
  var dates      = [];

  for(var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
    var endMonth = i != endYear ? 11 : parseInt(end[1]) - 1;
    var startMon = i === startYear ? parseInt(start[1])-1 : 0;
    for(var j = startMon; j <= endMonth; j = j > 12 ? j % 12 || 11 : j+1) {
      var month = j+1;
      var displayMonth = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
      dates.push([i, displayMonth, '01'].join('-'));
    }
  }
  return dates;
}
```

Just call it with your existing date format:

```
dateRange('2013-11-01', '2014-06-01')
// ["2013-11-01", "2013-12-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01", "2014-09-01", "2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01"]
```

Comment: Results seem to exceed the range of the input variable (you've input `2014-06-01`, but your result goes all the way to `2014-12-01`)

Comment: @ChrisVilla thanks for pointing that out, there was an issue with the `endMonth` calculation that should be resolved now.

Comment: Please use moment.js - datetime math is very tricky and error prone!

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the excellent moment.js library:

```
var startDate = moment('2012-04-01');
var endDate = moment('2014-11-01');

var result = [];

if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
    throw "End date must be greated than start date."
}      

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
    result.push(startDate.format("YYYY-MM-01"));
    startDate.add(1, 'month');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/1tp1hw8w/419/)

Comment: Looks like we don't need `currentDate` variable that clones startDate. Just do `result.push(startDate.format())`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @DimaEscaroda. I have incorporated your suggestion. One thing anyone copying this should be aware of is that startDate.add(1, 'month') mutates the startDate object. If startDate were instead passed in as a parameter to a function, you'd want to clone the startDate.

Comment: moment.js worth it for snippet like this.

Answer (score 8):

If loading an extra library isn't a problem, you could always try the awesome MomentJS.
Gives for very clean and powerful date manipulation.

```
var startDate = moment('2012-04-01');
var endDate = moment('2014-11-01');

var dates = [];
endDate.subtract(1, "month"); //Substract one month to exclude endDate itself

var month = moment(startDate); //clone the startDate
while( month < endDate ) {
    month.add(1, "month");
    dates.push(month.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

console.log(dates);
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MichielSteeg/mhzoopj6/)

Comment: This is the best answer for momentjs, because only here author doesn't change initial startDate's value.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const getMonths = (fromDate, toDate) => {
    const fromYear = fromDate.getFullYear();
    const fromMonth = fromDate.getMonth();
    const toYear = toDate.getFullYear();
    const toMonth = toDate.getMonth();
    const months = [];

    for(let year = fromYear; year <= toYear; year++) {
        let monthNum = year === fromYear ? fromMonth : 0;
        const monthLimit = year === toYear ? toMonth : 11;

        for(; monthNum <= monthLimit; monthNum++) {
            let month = monthNum + 1;
            months.push({ year, month });
        }
    }
    return months;
}

const sample = getMonths(new Date('2022-07-28'), new Date('2023-03-20'));
console.log(sample);
document.write('check the console output');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xfayoqvs/

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. If I pass `getMonths(new Date('2022-08-01'), new Date('2022-08-31'));` for instance, I get `[{ "year" 2022, "month": 7 }]`. I think you just need to change `month` in the push to be `month + 1`.

Comment: I've fixed your coding issue. The code sample should now work as expected. Your jsFiddle is still wrong however.

Answer (score 4):

You are handling "logical" jumps, so you doesn't actually need timing arthmetics. So this is a simple counting problem:

```
var startDate = '2012-04-01';
var endDate = '2014-11-01';
var dates = [];

var d0 = startDate.split('-');
var d1 = endDate.split('-');

for (
    var y = d0[0];
    y <= d1[0];
    y++
) {
    for (
        var m = d0[1];
        m <= 12;
        m++
    ) {
        dates.push(y+"-"+m+"-1");
        if (y >= d1[0] && m >= d1[1]) break;
    };
    d0[1] = 1;
};

console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which just uses string manipulation on that specific YYYY-MM-DD format:

```js
function monthsBetween(...args) {
    let [a, b] = args.map(arg => arg.split("-").slice(0, 2)
                                    .reduce((y, m) => m - 1 + y * 12));
    return Array.from({length: b - a + 1}, _ => a++)
        .map(m => ~~(m / 12) + "-" + ("0" + (m % 12 + 1)).slice(-2) + "-01");
}

console.log(monthsBetween('2012-04-01', '2014-11-01'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, using Date objects:

```js
const enumerateMonths = (from, to) => {
  const current = new Date(from)
  current.setUTCDate(1)
  current.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  const toDate = new Date(to)
  const months = []
  while (current.getTime() <= toDate.getTime()) {
    months.push(current.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + `${current.getUTCMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, "0"))
    current.setUTCMonth(current.getUTCMonth() + 1)
  }
  return months
}
```

This solution presumes you provide Date objects or ISO 8601 strings. Please mind that an ISO 8601 date does not necessarily have to contain the hours-minutes-seconds part. `"2012-01-14"` is a valid ISO 8601 date.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want to get list of months between today and last 11 months ago, try this.

```
const endDate = new Date(); // current date
const startDate = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth() - 11, 1); // 11 months ago
const months = [];

let currentDate = new Date(startDate);

while (currentDate <= endDate) {
  months.push(currentDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));
  currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
}

console.log(months); // ["May", "June", "July", ..., "March", "April"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example to get all first days of months between a given date and now using moment.js.

```
   var getMonths = function (startDate) {
    var dates = [];
    for (var year = startDate.year(); year <= moment().year(); year++) {
        var endMonth = year != moment().year() ? 11 : moment().month();
        var startMonth = year === startDate.year() ? startDate.month() : 0;
        for (var currentMonth = startMonth; currentMonth <= endMonth; currentMonth = currentMonth > 12 ? currentMonth % 12 || 11 : currentMonth + 1) {
            var month = currentMonth + 1;
            var displayMonth = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
            dates.push([year, displayMonth, '01'].join('-'));
        }
    }
    return dates;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All solutions above run in O(n^2) time complexity, which is not very efficient.
See below solution in O(n) time complexity:

```js
function getAllMonths(start, end){ 
 let startDate = new Date(start);
 let startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
 let startMonth = startDate.getMonth()+1;
 
 let endDate = new Date(end);
 let endYear = endDate.getFullYear();
 let endMonth = endDate.getMonth()+1;
 
 let countMonth = 0;
 let countYear = 0;
 let finalResult = [];

 for(let a=startYear; a<=endYear; a++){

  if(startYear<endYear){
   if(countYear==0){
    countMonth += 12-startMonth;
            }else 
   if(countYear>0){
    countMonth += 12;
            }
   countYear+=1;
   startYear++;
        }else 
  if(startYear==endYear){
   countMonth+=endMonth;
        }
    }
 for(let i=startMonth; i<=countMonth+startMonth; i++){
  finalResult.push(startDate.getFullYear()+(Math.floor(i/12)) + "-" + Math.round(i%13) + "-" + "01");
    }
 return finalResult;
}

getAllMonths('2016-04-01', '2018-01-01');
```

Might share a much more simpler code

Comment: this always returns 12 months if we test it for dates with a few months difference.
For example `getAllMonths('2018-8-01', '2018-11-01')` returns - `["2018-8", "2018-9", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2019-12", "2019-0", "2019-1", "2019-2", "2019-3", "2019-4", "2019-5", "2019-6"]`

Comment: *"...solutions above..."*: answers may appear in different orders. There is no absolute above or below here.

Answer (score -1):

Still not a very elegant answer, but arrives at the array of strings you want:

```
var startDate = '2012-04-01';
var endDate = '2014-11-01';
var start = new Date(startDate);
var end = new Date(endDate);
var dates = [];
for (var i = start.getFullYear(); i < end.getFullYear() + 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
      if (i === end.getFullYear() && j === end.getMonth() + 3) {
        break;
      }
      else if (i === 2012 && j < 4){
        continue;
      }
      else if (j < 10) {
        var dateString = [i, '-', '0' + j, '-','01'].join('');
        dates.push(dateString)
        }
      else {
        var dateString = [i, '-', j, '-','01'].join('');
        dates.push(dateString);
        }
    }
}
console.log(dates);
```

jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kut035a/

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, with help of math and O(n)

```
determineMonthInInterval(startDate, endDate) {

    let startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
    let endYear = endDate.getFullYear();

    let startMonth = startDate.getMonth() + 1;
    let endMonth = endDate.getMonth() + 1;

    let monthAmount = (endMonth - startMonth) + 1 + (12 * (endYear - startYear));

    let dates = [];
    let currMonth = startMonth;
    let currYear = startYear;
    for( let i=0; i<monthAmount; i++){
        
        let date = new Date(currYear + "/"+currMonth+"/1");
        dates.push(date);

        currYear = startYear + Math.floor((startMonth+i) / 12);
        currMonth = (currMonth) % 12 +1;

    }

    return dates;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is another option:

```
getRangeOfMonths(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    const dates = new Array<string>();
    const dateCounter = new Date(startDate);
    // avoids edge case where last month is skipped
    dateCounter.setDate(1);
    while (dateCounter < endDate) {
      dates.push(`${dateCounter.getFullYear()}-${dateCounter.getMonth() + 1}`);
      dateCounter.setMonth(dateCounter.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    return dates;
  }
```