# Year gets undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I`m have the following solution to get months for my calendar:

I`m newbie in react, could you please navigate me for right solution, thank you!

```
 getMonths(minDate, maxDate) {
    const { reverseOrder } = this.props;
    const months = [];
    const month = new Date(minDate.getFullYear(), minDate.getMonth());
    while (monthToString(month) <= monthToString(maxDate)) {
      months.push({
        month: month.getMonth(),
        year: month.getFullYear(),//get undefined;
      });
      month.setMonth(month.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    return reverseOrder ? months.reverse() : months;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: get all months between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464628/javascript-get-all-months-between-two-dates) more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925332/1008999

Comment: `monthToString` seems unnecessary. you shouldn't compare strings to be lower or equal to another string, you should compare numbers

Comment: @Endless trying use your example and with or without strings, but behavior still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare dates in the while loop (not strings)

```js
function getMonths(start, end) {
  const { reverseOrder } = this.props || {};
  const months = [];
  start = new Date(start) // copy the date
  while (start <= end) {
    months.push({
      month: start.getMonth(),
      year: start.getFullYear()
    });
    start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  return reverseOrder ? months.reverse() : months;
}

console.log(getMonths(new Date('2015-03-25'), new Date()))
```