# List of all the months that exists between the 2 dates including case when num difference between dates is less than 30 days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get a list of all the months that exists between the 2 dates in JS. For ex:

'2021-04-25' to '2021-05-12' should return [4,5] `//  case when num difference between dates is less than 30 days`

'2021-04-25' to '2021-08-12' should return [4,5,6,7,8]

'2021-10-25' to '2022-02-12' should return [10,11,12,1,2]

The following code works but doesn't give the right result for '2021-04-25' to '2021-05-12'. it returns only [4]

I tried examples [here JavaScript: get all months between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464628/javascript-get-all-months-between-two-dates) but momentjs not giving endMonth if days <30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good solution for get the results that you are looking for

```js
function getMonths(start, end) {
  start = moment(start).startOf('month');
  end = moment(end).startOf('month');

  if (start.isAfter(end))[start, end] = [end, start]; // This is only for order the dates

  const months = [];
  while (start.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
    months.push(start.month() + 1);
    start.add(1, 'months');
  }

  return months;
}

console.log(getMonths('2021-04-25', '2021-05-12'));
console.log(getMonths('2021-04-25', '2021-08-12'));
console.log(getMonths('2021-10-25', '2022-02-12'));
console.log(getMonths('2021-04-25', '2022-02-12'));
console.log(getMonths('2021-06-26', '2020-02-12'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [momentjs site](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) they say: "We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done."
You can use another library as the end-date.

Here is an example with the same logic proposed by AlTheLazyMonkey with date-fns

```
  import {
  addMonths,
  getMonth,
  isBefore,
  isEqual,
  startOfMonth
} from "date-fns";

let start = "2021-06-15";
let end = "2021-12-26";

const isSameOrBefore = (start, end) => {
  const result = (isBefore(start, end) || isEqual(start, end)) ?
    true :
    false
  return result
};

const getArrayOfMonths = (start, end) => {
  let startDate = startOfMonth(new Date(start));
  let endDate = startOfMonth(new Date(end));
  const arrayOfMonths = [];
  if (isBefore(endDate, startDate)) {
    console.log("End date must be greated than start date.");
  }

  while (isSameOrBefore(startDate, endDate)) {
    arrayOfMonths.push(getMonth(startDate) + 1);
    startDate = addMonths(startDate, 1);
  }
  return arrayOfMonths;
};

console.log(getArrayOfMonths(start, end));
console.log(getArrayOfMonths("2021-02-15", "2021-9-15"));
```