# Get the months between two dates JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

## Problem

First off, I am going to clarify that this question is not a duplicate of [Difference in months between two dates in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript) or [javascript month difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312825/javascript-month-difference?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question is specifically about getting the *months* in between two dates, not the *number* of months.

## Expected Results

So If `date1` is 11/01/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy) and `date2` is 02/20/2023, it should output an array of months including the month of `date1` and `date2` like `["November", "December", "January", "February"]`. I need to know how to return the actual months between two dates, not the number of months. Can somebody explain what would be the way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all the months that exists between the 2 dates including case when num difference between dates is less than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182964/list-of-all-the-months-that-exists-between-the-2-dates-including-case-when-num-d)

Comment: @ThomasSablik That question is specific to momentjs, my question is about just JavaScript.

Comment: The logic is exactly the same as in the accepted answer. The duplicate contains answers with momentjs and date-fns, but the same logic could be used with native `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post linked in the question is already a good start.

Maybe think about how you would do it when you want to write the results to a sheet of paper.

When we know the month to start, as an index [0...11], we can count from there and add the month names from an array:

```js
const xmas = new Date("December 25, 1999 23:15:30");
const summer = new Date("June 21, 2003 23:15:30");

function monthsBetween(dstart, dend) {
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let result = [];
    let current = dstart.getMonth();
    let end = (dend.getFullYear() - dstart.getFullYear()) * 12 + dend.getMonth();
    for (;current <= end; current += 1) {
        result.push(monthNames[current % 12]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(monthsBetween(xmas, summer)); // [December, January, February..., December, January, ...., June (multiple years)
console.log(monthsBetween(xmas, xmas)); // ["December"]
```

In your example 2022-11-01 to 2023-02-20, `current` would count from 10 (November, indexed from 0) to 13 (1: February indexed from 0 + 1 year = 12 months difference)

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks a lot! Also, apologies for not including a reproducible example as I am not on my main computer with code but had to ask this question at the earliest, but you got it nonetheless! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the dates from the start to the end, collecting the month names as you go.

The start and end should be *Date* objects, how you convert them from timestamps like "11/01/2022" is a separate concern and should be dealt with in a prior step.

```js
/* Get month names from start date to end date
 * @param {Date} start - date to start from
 * @param {Date} end - date to end at
 * @param {string} lang - language for month names
 * @returns {string[]} month names from start to end inclusive
 */
function getMonthNames(start = new Date(), end = new Date(), lang = 'en') {
  let d = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth());
  let months = [];
  while (d <= end) {
    months.push(d.toLocaleString(lang,{month:'long'}));
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  return months;
}

let start = new Date(2022, 10, 1);  // 01 Nov 2022
let end   = new Date(2023,  1, 20); // 20 Feb 2023 

console.log(getMonthNames(start, end))
```