# How to get list of months between 2 years in typescript for angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, datetime

I have a fromDate and toDate coming from a datepicker - Assuming the fromDate is 05-Sep-2021 and toDate is 02-Feb-2022, I need the list of the missing months between the two. I initially tried with the moment.js and using arr.reduce and arr.findIndex functions. But not getting the expected output. Kindly help.

Eg.

```
var arr = [
  {month: 7,  year: 2021, count: 21},
  {month: 12, year: 2021, count: 54},
  {month: 2,  year: 2022, count: 76}
];
```

Expected o/p =

```
[
  {month: 7,  year: 2021, count: 21}, 
  {month: 8,  year: 2021, count: 0},
  {month: 9,  year: 2021, count: 0},
  {month: 10, year: 2021, count: 0},
  {month: 11, year: 2021, count: 0},
  {month: 12, year: 2021, count: 54},
  {month: 1,  year: 2022, count: 0},
  {month: 2,  year: 2022, count: 76}
];
```

Comment: Yes, even that is to be included in the expected op

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: get all months between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464628/javascript-get-all-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: Why source array has 3 items? Not just `from` and `to` dates?

Comment: @AlexandrBelan  Because there is a count too.   It looks like he wants to keep those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to think of the Year & Month as one value.
eg.  `var ym = year * 12 + (month - 1)`

If you do this then you can compare the YM value to the next item in the array, if it's below then you can insert a new item into the array between them.

> Update, added two utility function to make this easier, YM, will basically convert Year/Month into a linear number, and then RYM will convert this number back into `{year, month}`, Bonus, I think it makes the code slightly easier to follow too.

Below is an example..

```js
var arr = [
  {month: 7,  year: 2021, count: 21},
  {month: 12, year: 2021, count: 54},
  {month: 2,  year: 2022, count: 76}
];

/*var arr = [
  {month: 11, year: 2021, count: 54}, 
  {month: 2, year: 2022, count: 76} 
]; */

const YM = ({year, month}) => year * 12 + month - 1;

const RYM = ym => ({
   year: Math.trunc(ym / 12), 
   month: (ym % 12) + 1
});


function fillSpace(arr) {
  let st = 0;
  while (st < arr.length -1){
    const thisYM = YM(arr[st]);
    const nextYM = YM(arr[st + 1]);
    if (thisYM + 1 < nextYM) 
      arr.splice(st + 1, 0, {
        ...RYM(thisYM + 1),
        count: 0
      });     
    st += 1;
  }
}

fillSpace(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, Here assuming there are only 2 objects in the array, For ex - let arr = [{month: 11, year: 2021, count: 54},  {month: 2,  year: 2022, count: 76} ,
12 month is not getting displayed..

Comment: @arv  Ah, yes,.. forgetting months are 1 based, and not 0 based.. :), give us a tick I'll update

Comment: @arv  Ok, updated..  Added two utility function YM & RYM these help with converting from Year Month to a single value, and back again.

Answer (score -2):

new Date(new Date(d2) - new Date(d1)).getMonth();

Comment: The response you proposed does not solve the statement.

Comment: oh sorry. But thanks.