# Moment.js not working as I expected for getting months between two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the month list between two dates. The start  and end dates I took it from an array. I used `moment.js` to do this. Here is my code

```
    var Start = moment(new Date(data2[0])).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
var End = moment(new Date(data2[data2.length-1])).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

console.log(Start) //It prints 2018-08-08
console.log(End)   //It prints 2019-01-04

var dateStart = moment(Start)
var dateEnd = moment(End)
var timeValues = [];


while (moment(dateEnd) > moment(dateStart) || moment(dateStart).format('MM') === moment(dateEnd).format('MM')) {
   timeValues.push(moment(dateStart).format('YYYY-MM'));
   moment(dateStart).add(1,'month');
}

alert (timeValues)
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466944/how-to-list-all-month-between-2-dates-with-moment-js)

The error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: dateStart.format is not a function
```

Please correct me where I'm doing wrong

console
[image: console.log]

Comment: `moment(data2[0]).format("DD/MM/YYYY");`  You are not creating a moment date, you have now made it into a string, and yes, strings don't have format.

Comment: edited the question. please check now

Comment: It's still the same,.  `dateStart ` is a string, because you made it into a string using the `format` function.   The link you got the code from doesn't do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.format("DD/MM/YYYY");` you are returning a **String**.

A string does not have `format` function as the error message states.

```
                                v -- error here
var dateStart = moment(data2[0]).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

The line above returns a `String`, you want to use `format` function in a moment `Date` object.

Try something like this (assumnig that `data2[data2.length-1]` and `data2[0]` are valid Dates):

```
 var dateStart = moment(new Date(data2[0]));
 var dateEnd = moment(new Date(data2[data2.length-1]));
```

I have made a [live example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQNWve) using  code pen check it out.

---

#### Updated question

Try using this code

```
var dateStart = moment("2018-08-08").format("DD/MM/YYYY"); //#08/08/2018
var dateEnd = moment("2019-04-01").format("DD/MM/YYYY"); //#01/04/2019

var timeValues = [];
dateEndObj = moment(dateEnd);
dateStartObj = moment(dateStart);

while (dateEndObj > dateStartObj || dateStartObj.format('MM') === dateEndObj.format('MM')) {
   timeValues.push(dateStartObj.format('YYYY-MM'));
   dateStartObj.add(1,'month');
}

alert (timeValues);
```

Comment: Why are you using format in the first two lines, that is the error, because format is returning a **string**, can you show a `console.log()` of `data2[0]` and `data2[data2.length-1]`?

Comment: please find the console

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment, check the provided link

Comment: from your live example I understand it is working but I need to change the date format since the array returns the different format

Comment: I have attached the console image

Comment: I just updating the answer, in your question update you are converting back the formatted date to moment date object `var dateStart = moment(Start)` , so, the `while (moment(dateEnd)...` wrapper in the while and inside it, is not necessary