# Chart.js (chartjs-node-canvas) create date-based floating bar graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I will attempt to explain my issue as clearly as possible while also avoid making this topic too long. I recently found the Chart.js library, which is excellent for what I need. Now, since I am using Node.js and need a png of the graph, I am utilizing the `chartjs-node-canvas` library. Having this information in mind, I will try to split my topic into multiple sections for a clearer understanding.

#### Ultimate Goal

Before getting into the problem itself, I would like to discuss my ultimate goal. This is to give a general idea on what I'm trying to do so the responses are fitted accordingly. To keep this short, I have data in the form of `{awardedDate: "2022-06-22T12:21:17.22Z", badgeId: 1234567}`, with `awardedDate` being a timestamp of when the badge was awarded, and the `badgeId` being the ID of the badge that was awarded (which is irrelevant to the graph, but it exists because it's part of the data). Now, I have a sample with around 2,787 of these objects, with all having different award dates and IDs, and with dates ranging from 2016 to 2022. My objective is to group these badges by month-year, and that month-year will have the amount of badges earned for that month during that year. With that data, I then want to make a waterfall graph which is based on the amount of badges earned that month of that year. As of right now, there isn't a specific structure on how this will look like, but it could range from an object that looks like `{"02-2022": 10, "03-2022": 5}` to anything else. I can of course restructure this format based on what is required for a waterfall graph.

#### Actual Questions

Now that you have a general idea of what my ultimate goal is, my actual question is how I'd be able to make a floating (we can leave the waterfall structure stuff for another topic) bar graph with that data. Since the data can have blank periods (it is possible for a dataset to have gaps that are months long), I cannot really utilize labels (unless I am saying something wrong), so an x-y relation works the best. I tried using the structure of `{x: "2022-06-22T12:21:17.226Z", y: [10, 15]}`, but that didn't really yield any results. As of right now, I am using a sample code to test how the graph reacts with the data, and of course I'll replace the test values with actual values once I have a finished product. Here is my code so far:

```js
    const config = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: "Badges",
                data: [
                    {
                        x: "2022-06-22T12:41:17.226Z",
                        y: [10, 15]
                    }
                ],
                borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                borderSkipped: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Test",
                    color: "#FFFFFF"
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Time',
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    min: "2022-06-22T12:21:17.226Z",
                    max: "2022-06-22T14:21:17.226Z",
                    grid: {
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Number of Badges',
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 50,
                    grid: {
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            {
                id: 'custom_canvas_background_color',
                beforeDraw: (chart) => {
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
                    ctx.restore();
                  }
            }
        ]
    };

    const imageBuffer = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer(config)

    fs.writeFileSync("./chart2.png", imageBuffer)
```

And this is the graph that the code produces:
[image: graph]

What is supposed to happen, of course, is that a float bar should be generated near the start that ranges from 5 to 10, but as seen above, nothing happens. If someone could assist me in my problem, that would be amazing. Thank you very much for your time and help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61708696/2358409), I came up with the following solution.

```js
const baseData = [
 { awardedDate: "2022-06-22T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-06-18T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-06-15T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-05-20T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-05-10T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-04-16T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-04-09T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-04-03T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-04-01T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-02-18T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-02-12T12:21:17.22Z" }, 
 { awardedDate: "2022-01-17T12:21:17.22Z" }
];

const badgesPerMonth = baseData
  .map(o => o.awardedDate)
  .sort()
  .map(v => moment(v))
  .map(m => m.format('MMM YYYY'))
  .reduce((acc, month) => {
    const badges = acc[month] || 0;
    acc[month] = badges + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
const months = Object.keys(badgesPerMonth);
const labels = months.concat('Total');
const data = [];
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  const vStart = total;
  total += badgesPerMonth[months[i]];
  data.push([vStart, total]);  
}
data.push(total);
const backgroundColors = data
  .map((o, i) => 'rgba(255, 99, 132, ' + (i + (11 - data.length)) * 0.1 + ')');

new Chart('badges', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Badges',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 0.95
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: ctx => {
            const v = data[ctx.dataIndex];
            return Array.isArray(v) ? v[1] - v[0] : v;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="badges" height="95"></canvas>
```

> If you also want to see the gaps, you would first have to initialize `badgesPerMonth` with following months between the earliest and latest date, each with value zero. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595037/2358409) to get an idea about how this could be done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I modified my code a bit and utilized the `min` and `max` properties for the actual range itself. From there, I made some loops to organize my tables. All in all though, your reply was what gave me a general idea of what I had to do, so big thanks!

(The actual code used is in the reply below)

Answer (score 0):

After reading @uminder's reply, I was able to create the following code which solved my problem:

```js
    dateGroups = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(dateGroups).sort(([d1,],[d2,]) => {return (d1 < d2) ? -1 : ((d1 > d2) ? 1 : 0)})
    )
    const dateTimesConst = Object.keys(dateGroups)
    const dateValuesConst = Object.values(dateGroups)
    let dateTimes = []
    let dateValues = []
    let prevLength = 0
    let mostBadgesPerMonth = 0
    
    for (let i = 0; i < dateValuesConst.length; i++) {
        const currentMonth = new Date(Date.parse(dateTimesConst[i]))
        const previousMonth = new Date(Date.UTC(currentMonth.getUTCFullYear(), currentMonth.getUTCMonth() - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString()
        const nextMonth = new Date(Date.UTC(currentMonth.getUTCFullYear(), currentMonth.getUTCMonth() + 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString()

        // if (!dateTimesConst.includes(previousMonth)) prevLength = 0


        const length = dateValuesConst[i].length
        dateValues.push([prevLength, length])
        dateTimes.push(dateTimesConst[i])
        prevLength = length
        if (length > mostBadgesPerMonth) mostBadgesPerMonth = length

        // if (!dateTimesConst.includes(nextMonth) && i !== dateValuesConst.length - 1) {
        //     dateTimes.push(nextMonth)
        //     dateValues.push([length, 0])
        //     prevLength = 0
        // }
    }

    function barColorCode() {
        return (ctx) => {
            const start = ctx.parsed._custom.start
            const end = ctx.parsed._custom.end

            return start <= end ? "rgba(50, 168, 82, 1)" : (start > end) ? "rgba(191, 27, 27, 1)" : "black"
        }
    }

    const config = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: dateTimes,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Badges",
                data: dateValues,
                elements: {
                    bar: {
                        backgroundColor: barColorCode()
                    }
                },
                barPercentage: 1,
                categoryPercentage: 0.95,
                borderSkipped: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Test",
                    color: "#FFFFFF"
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Date',
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    time: {
                        unit: "month",
                        round: "month"
                    },
                    min: dateTimesConst[0],
                    max: dateTimesConst[dateTimesConst.length - 1],
                    grid: {
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Number of Badges',
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: mostBadgesPerMonth + 1,
                    grid: {
                        borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            {
                id: 'custom_canvas_background_color',
                beforeDraw: (chart) => {
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
                    ctx.restore();
                  }
            }
        ]
    };

    const imageBuffer = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer(config)

    fs.writeFileSync("./chart2.png", imageBuffer)
```

Again, big thanks to @uminder for the inspiration.